# ArcGIS Enterprise view branch version differences between two points in time

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, versioning, arcgis-enterprise

When I try and see the differences between one moment and another using Branched Versioning (through the REST API), I can only see the differences of the latest version that was checked in.

Workflow:

- Edit a feature class in one version
- Rec and Post the version
- Edit a feature class (or same) in another version (could even be the same version)
- Rec and Post the Version
- Try and view differences of the default version via the REST API
- Start reading
- set the from moment to the time prior the time of the first Rec and post (from step 2 above)
- get differences: example url:
  Https://gisserver.com/arcgis/rest/services/editingservice/VersionManagementServer/versions/B473F418-...

sessionid:  1701977451347

fromMoment: "1701977451220"

resultType: objectids

The return set of differences comes back with ONLY the changes from the second Rec and Post (from step 4 above).

Is my process correct for obtaining the differences from multiple rec and posts? Is this even possible?

I'm using ArcGIS Enterprise 10.9.1

Comment: If anyone else has experienced this issue add a comment. Want to make sure it's not just me :)